# Powershell - Issues with Exception Handling when trying to return objects with inaccessible expanded properties

Tags: powershell, exception

I tried to ask on techcommunity but that site is a nightmare, gave up after an hour.

Trying to understand what's wrong with the proposed adjustments to handle exceptions when selecting expanding properties on objects, and options to correctly do this.

Assume it requires exception handling - recently been playing with Ruby and equivalent can be achieved on each-object `_` in a iterator using something *like*

`puts _ unless _.nil?`

```
Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -Erroraction Silentlycontinue | 
Select Name -ExpandProperty Events | Format-Table Name, ID, Description
```

**The system cannot find the file specified

The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file**

v2 (makes it worse!)

```
try {
    $events = Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Events
    }

    if ($events) {
        $events | Format-Table Name, ID, Description
    } else {
        Write-Host "No events found."
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
}
```

v3 still not working (script running, nothing returned)

```
try {
    $events = Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Events) {
            $_ | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Events
        }
    }

    if ($events) {
        $events | Format-Table Name, ID, Description
    } else {
        Write-Host "No events found."
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` to filter the input objects:

```
Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -Erroraction Silentlycontinue |
Where-Object { $null -ne $_.Events } |
Select Name -ExpandProperty Events | Format-Table Name, ID, Description
```